# How to know the connection configuration in Outlook if the mail profile is automatically fed?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail

I have a question regarding Outlook 2010 (or 2007) email connection config. Normally, for example when you want to use outlook to check out mail from Gmail, you can manually config the connection (enter the account name, password, smtp address, port,....) then it's all set.

However when I join the new company, all the computers (all run Windows 7) in the company network must join the domain, and after I installed Outlook, it (magically - to me) got all the account name, connection settings, and the email started loading. I don't have to enter information into Outlook.

Problem is, I don't like using Outlook at all, and I love checking and sending through a web-based email (like Gmail). Gmail has a wonderful feature to allow user enter smtp information so it can retrieve and send email through the company server. Before, I always have the information to feed in Gmail, but now with the automatic email settings from the joined domain computer, I don't know where to get such kind of information.

Anyone can help? My appreciation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools -> Account Settings

It's not SMTP though, it's MAPI (Exchange).

I would be stunned if your company allows SMTP relaying from outside. I doubt you'll be happy with MS Webmail either, as it tries very hard to mimic the Outlook interface.

If it's open to the outside, your IT dept. will need to give you the details.

Comment: Thanks LilCodger. Before I always use Gmail to check and send if the GUI of the web-based which an institution provided is too ugly or too hard to navigate. Normally I always found the necessary information to fetch to Gmail. This is the first time I check mail in Outlook with MAPI exchange.
The IT dept said that there's a way to check mail outside the company, but a VPN is needed, so I doubt that I can use Gmail to check mail.

Comment: If you need VPN, then nope, no chance of Gmail pulling it without an elaborate mechanism.